# How to make Intervals go in a row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, jsx, setinterval

I've been trying to make a Pomodoro timer with user's defined time to work and rest. I have a Timer component that have this starting logic:

```
useEffect(() => {
    start(3);
    start(timeData.workTime);
    start(timeData.restTime);
}, [])

const start = (time) => {
    currentTime.current = time;
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        intervalRef.current = intervalId;
        if (currentTime.current === 0) {
            stop();
            currentTimeEnds.current = true;
        }

        timerRef.current.innerHTML = `
            ${validateTime(minutes)}:${validateTime(seconds)}
        `
        currentTime.current--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

The first function call is a countdown before timer starts it's work. timeData.workTime and timeData.restTime is being fetched from context.
The problem is that intervals are being called async and it's not rendering workTime and countdown on the page. So, I am trying to call them the "sync" way, or maybe there's better solution to my problem? Can somebody help, please?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure how to update you want to re-render your content, but I have made an implementation for a counter function that you could chain to get sequential counters:

```js
function counter(time) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
         console.log(time)
         // Your code goes here 
          resolve(1)
      }, time)
   })
}

// Testing
const time1 = 1500
const time2 = 2000
const time3 = 2500
counter(time1)
   .then(() => counter(time2))
   .then(() => counter(time3))
```